# Replace multiple strings within textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string, dictionary, replace

I have a working code that replaces multiple strings within a textarea.
However it only replaces strings that are written onLoad in my textarea.

I want to paste some text into the textarea and replace it afterwards.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
see: http://jsfiddle.net/yXm5P/
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="change" value="change all">

<textarea class="input">Schwarz -- doesn't work for text, that was pasted into textarea, onLoad text only....why???</textarea>
```

Here's my script:

```
$(".change").click(function() {
var dictionary= {
"Schwarz":"#000000",
"Braun":"#6F3E18",
"Beige":"#D4BE8D",
"Grau":"#838383",
"Weiß":"#FFFFFF",
"Dunkelblau":"#0000A0",
"Blau":"#345AFF",
"Hellblau":"#32CAEB",
"Türkis":"#22A2A4",
"Grün":"#25B53A",
"Gelb":"#FFFC00",
"Orange":"#FF6501",
"Rot":"#EA0001",
"Pink":"#ED008C",
"Hell Lila":"#9349AA",
"Dunkel Lila":"#663376",
"Mehrfarbig":"#mcol"   
};

$("body *").each( function(){
    for( var ptrn in dictionary){
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(new RegExp(ptrn ,"g"), dictionary[ptrn] ) );
    }
});
      alert( "done" );


});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yXm5P/

Comment: what are you asking? You have a click event handler and it works. What is that you want. Also paste some code snippets in your question and don't resort to trick the SO's filter

Comment: I want to paste some text into the textarea, click on a button and change the pasted text, according to the dictonary.

(i'll paste my code now, however it is available here  
jsfiddle.net/yXm5P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.text()` is NOT the correct way to get/set a textarea's value. `.val()` is.

Use the right function and the right result should happen ;)

Comment: do you have microscope in your eyes :) (*added smiley to get rid of dis-ambiguity*)

Comment: @AmitJoki Sniper scope lenses have been surgically inserted in my eyes to replace my biological lenses.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the right version of your jsFiddle with the .val() selector:
[JSfiddle replace text](http://jsfiddle.net/yXm5P/4/)

```
$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(
```